# TypeScript: False argument error for function overloads -- TS Limitation?

Tags: typescript

I wanted to create a wrapper for the jQuery `$` method but TypeScript kept throwing errors. I isolated the problem as following:

```
function x(q: string): number;
function x(q: number): number;
function x(q: string | number) { return (typeof q === 'string') ? parseInt(q): q; }
function xx(qq: string | number) {
    return x(qq);
}
```

which gives me:

```
Error   TS2769  (TS) No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(q: string): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(q: number): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'. D:\project\Scripts\ts (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    D:\project\Scripts\ts\Components\JQueryExtensions.ts    13  Active
```

As screenshot:

[image]

I understand the error message. I also know how to avoid the error (`as any`). My question is: Shouldn't TypeScript notice that `qq` and `q` are actually of the same type and thus allow this code? Is this a known limitation of TypeScript? Btw, I am using TS 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually only first two `x()` declarations are visible, the implementation itself is considered invisible. If you want to make it also visible, you should add it explicitly to the overload list, like:

```js
function x(q: string): number;
function x(q: number): number;
function x(q: string | number): number;
function x(q: string | number) { return (typeof q === 'string') ? parseInt(q): q; }
function xx(qq: string | number) {
    return x(qq);
}
```

But, in this case the first two overloads doesn't make sense, as well as the new one, because it matches the implementation, you can just remove the overloads.

```js
function x(q: string | number) { return (typeof q === 'string') ? parseInt(q): q; }
function xx(qq: string | number) {
    return x(qq);
}
```

Comment: That explains the behavior: "the implementation itself is considered invisible", so indeed it seems to be a known limitation of TS. As for the overloads: Sure they make no sense, they are just a minimal example. In "real life" `x()` is `$()` which I really do not want to remove. But still a good answer since it points the finger at the root problem and provides a solution approach.